# using foreach loop to delete last element from associative array

Tags: php, foreach, associative-array

I want to delete price index from each of the array.

Here is a sample code:

```
Array([0] => Array
    (
        [player_id] => 108
        [trnmnt_team_id] => 1
        [player_type] => 1
        [user_team_id] => 11
        [user_id] => 4
        [price] => 10.00
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [player_id] => 151
        [trnmnt_team_id] => 2
        [player_type] => 1
        [user_team_id] => 11
        [user_id] => 4
        [price] => 10.00
    )
)
```

I tried to delete following way but it shown unexpected `'unset' (T_UNSET)`:

```
foreach ($mergeAllType as $key => $value) {
    $price=$value;
    $withOutPrice[]=unset($price['price']);
}
```

Comment: remove the `$withOutPrice[]=` bit. unset() does not return anything.

Comment: I need the same array without price element.
how I get rest of the elements??@FranzGleichmann

Comment: It's directly changes your input array (is passed by reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php#refsect1-function.unset-returnvalues) doesn't returns any value (it's language construct, not a function), you must do it following way:

```
unset($price['price']);
$withOutPrice[] = $price;
```

Answer (score 1):

Tomas.lang's answer works fine if you know the last index's key. However if you don't know the name of the last key you could use the following:

```
unset(end($price));
$withOutPrice = $price;
```

Answer (score 0):

You already got your answers regarding your foreach loop.
So, let me give you a different answer, using [array_map](http://docs.php.net/array_map) and an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) ;-)

```
<?php
$src = array(
    array (
        'player_id' => 108,
        'trnmnt_team_id' => 1,
        'player_type' => 1,
        'user_team_id' => 11,
        'user_id' => 4,
        'price' => 10.00,
    ),
    array (
        'player_id' => 151,
        'trnmnt_team_id' => 2,
        'player_type' => 1,
        'user_team_id' => 11,
        'user_id' => 4,
        'price' => 10.00,
    ),
);

$withOutPrice = array_map(
    function($e) {
        unset($e['price']);
        return $e;
    },
    $src
);

var_export($withOutPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to `unset()` all off the `price` keys in your array you can use `array_walk()`

```
array_walk($arr, function(&$array) {
    unset($array['price']);
});
```

Just replace `$arr` with whatever your arrays name is, i.e. `$teams`.

If you want to have two arrays, one with price and one without price you could duplicate the array before doing the above; i.e.

```
$teams = <DATASOURCE>
$teamsWithoutPrice = $teams;

array_walk($teamsWithoutPrice, function(&$array) {
    unset($array['price']);
});
```

Then if you print out your `$teamsWithoutPrice` array you'll have your array with the `price` key removed.

Hope it helps.